# How to compare nullables in Vb.Net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

C# is straightforward. If you have the following code there will be no surprises:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Test(null, null,null,null));
}
static bool Test(int? firstLeft, int? firstRigt, int? secondLeft, int? secondRight)
{
    return firstLeft == firstRigt && secondLeft == secondRight;
}
```

Apparently `True` will be printed as the result. Let's try to do something like this in VB:

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine(Test(Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing))
End Sub

Function Test(FirstLeft As Integer?, FirstRight As Integer?, SecondLeft As Integer?, SecondRight As Integer?) As Boolean
    Return FirstLeft = FirstRight AndAlso SecondLeft = SecondRight
End Function
```

Can you guess what result will be? `True`? Wrong. `False`? Wrong. The result will be `InvalidOperationException`.

That's because the type of nullable comparison result is not `Boolean`, it's `Boolean?`. This mean when on either side of your comparison you have `Nothing`, the result of the comparison won't be `True`or `False`, it will be `Nothing`. No wonder when you try to combine that with other comparison results it does not go down well.

I would like to learn the most idiomatic way to rewrite this function in VB. Here is the best I can do:

```
Function Test(FirstLeft As Integer?, FirstRight As Integer?, SecondLeft As Integer?, SecondRight As Integer?) As Boolean
    'If one value has value and the other does not then they are not equal
    If (FirstLeft.HasValue AndAlso Not FirstRight.HasValue) OrElse (Not FirstLeft.HasValue AndAlso  FirstRight.HasValue) Then Return False

    'If they both have value and the values are different then they are not equal
    If FirstLeft.HasValue AndAlso FirstRight.HasValue AndAlso FirstLeft.Value <> FirstRight.Value  Then Return False

    'Ok now we are confident the first values are equal. Lets repeat the excerise with second values
    If (SecondLeft.HasValue AndAlso Not SecondRight.HasValue) OrElse (Not SecondLeft.HasValue AndAlso  SecondRight.HasValue) Then Return False
    If SecondLeft.HasValue AndAlso SecondRight.HasValue AndAlso SecondLeft.Value <> SecondRight.Value  Then Return False
    Return True            
End Function
```

This works, but having seen the C# version of this code I can't shake the feeling that it can be implemented simpler. In this particular case only two pairs are compared, in other cases there may be more than two, and the code above becomes event more verbose and you are forced to extract a method for comparing two values, which feels like an overkill.

What is a more idiomatic way of comparing nullable values in VB?

Comment: Se- vb.net have same idiomatic way of comparing nullable values as C# has :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Function Test(FirstLeft As Integer?, FirstRight As Integer?, SecondLeft As Integer?, SecondRight As Integer?) As Boolean
    'Note the HasValue are both false, this function will return true
    Return Nullable.Equals(FirstLeft, FirstRight) AndAlso Nullable.Equals(SecondLeft, SecondRight)
End Function
```

[Nullable.Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/213d9ey9(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

[image]